# N-Way Merge If Arrays Are Generally Different

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I understand that using a min heap is generally the best way to perform and N-way merge or sorted arrays. However, would that still be the case if the arrays were fairly unique from each other in value (with little overlap). For example, we could have these arrays:

A: {7,11,14,16,18}

B: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

C: {120,130,140,150,160,170,180}

D: {35,70,140,141,142}

Would using a min heap still be the best way to solve this problem? Could it be possible that it would be more efficient to first combine the arrays in the order {B,A,D,C}, then perform a bubble sort? That seems like it would yield a complexity of  Θ(NlogN + M) where M is the total number of entries, which is a bit faster than the Θ(MlogN) from a standard N-way merge.

Now, what if we were to increased the amount of overlap between the arrays, or add a few arrays with high amount of overlap. At what point would the optimal solution be the min heap?

Comment: I don't agree with your  Θ(NlogN + M) result. Certainly, combining the arrays into one takes O(M) time. If you then run a bubble sort, each pass of the bubble sort takes an additional O(M) time. Which leaves the question: "How many passes of the bubble sort are needed?" So the overall running time is O(M + MX), where `X` is the number of passes needed by the bubble sort. `X` is not a function of `N`. Instead it depends on the amount of overlap between the arrays.

Comment: Consider bubble sort on {A,B}, that's still a O(n^2) process with a smaller constant factor. In this case, the 1 in B takes 5 compares and swaps to place. The 2 through 6 in B each take 6 compares and 5 swaps to place, and so on.

Comment: The other observation I'll make (inspired by rcgldr's original comment), is that your example never needs anything more than a two-way merge. That's because array B is completed depleted before array D begins. And even array A is completely depleted before array D begins. So the merge degenerates to a two-merge between B and A, followed by a two-way merge between D and C. That's a partial answer to your question. If the overlap is such that no three arrays ever overlap, then the problem degenerates to multiple two-way merges, and a min heap is not needed.

Comment: Sort of on that train of thought, why use a heap at all for an N-way merge? The Wikipedia article for this problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-way_merge_algorithm) says they have the same complexity, with the iterative 2-way merge better in some cases if you iteratively merge your two shortest arrays.

Comment: Having read the article, I agree that there doesn't seem to be any compelling reason to use a heap. On the other hand, maybe you have the code for a min heap, and you just want to try it out :)

Comment: Using a heap makes more sense in the case of the merge phases of an external sort, where a K-way merge requires logk(N) merge phases, where each phase involves N reads and N writes.

Comment: On a processor with 16 registers, such as an X86 in 64 bit mode, with 8 of those registers used as pointers (or references) to start and end of 4 runs, a 4-way merge is a bit faster than 2 way merge. The total number of operations is the same, 1.5 x compares and 0.5x moves, but the compares are a bit more cache + memory "friendly" than the moves (writes). A K-way min heap reduces moves and increase compares by log(K), but it's using a local array (instead of registers) to contain the heap, and I'm not sure if it's faster or not.